# how can I insert Tags HTML with javascript in a precise position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insertafter

I need to add HTML Tags in a precise position using Javascript

```
<div id="myId">
   <div id="addAfter"><div>
   <***here I need to add a set off HTML Tags***>
   <div ><div>
   <div><div>
</div>
```

javascript code

```
  var ol = '<ol id ="div_blue"><li><img id="blueUp" src="<c:url    value="/resources/style/images/btup.png"/>" alt =""/></li><li>....</li>< /ol>' ;
  $("#myId").InsertInPosition2(ol);
```

but how to define InsertInPosition2?

thanks

imprim ecran

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after)

```
$("#addAfter").after(ol);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BeEKA/)

If you want to add the element with reference to the parent element then

```
$("#myId").children().first().after(ol);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZRYac/)

Comment: yes it's nice but I have a problem too with the attribute src = ".../btup.png" I noticed that this method create a new img called btup.png but I have already this image and I need just to use it and not to create a new one
so I have this error GET http://localhost:8084/resources/style/images/btup.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @LallouDaddou what is the path to the existing image

Comment: the same path src="/resources/style/images/btup.png"

Comment: if the path is the same then how are you getting a 404

Comment: because he create a new one 
I'll add a capture screen

Comment: what is the resource path for the first and second request they seems to be different..

Comment: this the original : <li><img id="redUp" src="<c:url value="/resources/style/images/btup.png"/>" alt="" /></li>

this generate with javascript :  var ol = '<ol id ="div_blue"><li><img id="blueUp" src="/resources/style/images/btup.png"/></li></ol>'

Comment: it's really the same path and I don't know why it create a new one

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42662/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-lallou-daddou)